# "I will see if I can't make somthing", what does the "can't" mean?

Tags: grammar, negation

The line is easy to understand in context but difficult in terms of grammar. I find this one in D.H. Lawrence's famous short fiction The Rocking-Horse Winner so it may be of common use in his age or it's written for the particular purpose of this literature work. For reference, it's  the first sentence in the fourth paragraph, a sentence said by the mother in the fiction.

Answer (score 4):

You noted that you understood it from context, but for clarity in this answer, the phrase:

> "I will see if I *can't* make something."

means

> "I will see if I *can* make something."

To be clear, both constructions are 100% grammatically correct.  They have very slightly different meanings but are used nearly interchangeably.  The former literally means that they will check to see if something is impossible, while the latter means that they will check to see if it is possible.

The usage of this redundant negative is largely limited to a situation where a challenge is anticipated or someone is offering assistance to another person who has been struggling.  It is used in the context of being able to overcome that challenge or difficulty and resolve the problem at hand.  In terms of constructing a sentence, it is usually used in conjunction with verbs meaning "to discover," most often *to see*, but other verbs like find out, check, etc are possible.

Let's say that some friends drop by your house and everyone is hungry.  You haven't been shopping for a little while and your pantry just has odds and ends, nothing that makes a clear, obvious meal.  You might say:

> "Let's see if I can't turn these ingredients into something edible."

and thereby acknowledge and slightly emphasize the challenge that you're facing, but implying that you think you'll make something tasty.  You might also just say:

> "Let's see if I can turn these ingredients into something edible."

and likely no fluent speaker would notice the difference if you said it with a positive, confident attitude.

The negative construction is less formal as well, and is used almost exclusively in spoken language.  If I were writing instructions, for instance, I would never use the negative version of this.

Oddly enough, the negative construction also has a sense of positivity to it that the positive construction lacks.

> Let's see if we can get this wheelchair ramp built for Grandpa before he gets out of the hospital.
> **versus**
> Let's see if we can't get this wheelchair ramp built for Grandpa before he gets out of the hospital.

The former might be encouraging everyone to work hard, or it might just be posing the question, "Can we get the job done in time?"  The latter is definitely encouraging people to work hard, and it's framed as a challenge for the people involved to get the work done in time.

Answer (score 0):

> Let's see if we can't .... [succeed at something]

This expression is often said to a beginner by a person who has more experience and feels confident of success after some relatively minor adjustments to approach.

As Jason remarks in his answer, it has a "positivity", an optimism and confidence, but the negative **can't** also adds some *gentleness* to the instruction inasmuch as it acknowledges that what the beginner finds challenging is real, that it is indeed something that requires mastery  -- it is not that the beginner is maladept.